# Position tag in css prevents use of hyperlinks

Tags: css, hyperlink, position, conflict

**NEWBIE ALERT** In Firefox, but not IE hyperlinks do not work because of `position: relative;` tag. I am confident this is it because if I remove the tag the hyperlinks work fine. URL is http://www.dryerase.com/g1116-2x-test.htm or you may use http://dryerase.com/Default-sidebar-test-4.htm they both have the same CSS. I am also confident that it is not HTML because it works the same on both sites mentioned. However I did use one as a template. Thanks ahead of time for your insight.

```
#Content_Wrapper { 

position:relative;
top:-30px;
display: table;
width: 960px;
min-height:500px;
max-height:auto; 
z-index:-10;

-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);

-webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with z-index. The #Page_Wrapper is in front of #Content_Wrapper, so you cannot click in links. The z-index property is considered only if element has a position, so when you remove it, link works because it doesn't have a valid z-index property.

IE understands z-index in a different way.